# progressbar does not work in c#

Tags: progress-bar, backgroundworker

```
        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.progressBar2.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        //progressBar2.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }
    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "cancelled";
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {

            throw e.Error;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0} files updated", e.Result);
        }
    }
    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                string password = @"myKey123"; // Your Key Here
                UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
                byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

                string cryptFile = EncryOutputFile;

                FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);

                RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

                CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                    RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
                    CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(EncryInputFile, FileMode.Open);

                int data;
                double counter = 1;
                while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                {
                    cs.WriteByte((byte)data);
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)((counter / fsIn.Length) * 100));
                    counter++;
                }

                fsIn.Close();
                cs.Close();
                fsCrypt.Close();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

progressbar does not work.
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)((counter / fsIn.Length) * 100));
Add this sentence and it will not work...
And.. Encryption was very slow after adding more than before. :(

Comment: Integer division, result is zero. First multiply by 100, then divide, or calculate with floating point.

Comment: backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)(fsIn.Length*100/counter));
not work .. what can i do?

Comment: counter * 100 / fsln.Length. Also don't report progress *every byte*, that surely will slow everything Dow

Comment: thank you. But what should I do? I do not know....Let me know an example.

Comment: int data;
                    double counter = 1;
                    while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                    {
                        cs.WriteByte((byte)data);
                        if (data == 0)
                        {
                            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)(counter * 100 / fsIn.Length));
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }

Comment: I had to make this change. But it encrypts twice.